# Print / log Jenkins (Vulnerarbility / Plugin) Warnings

Tags: security, jenkins, groovy, plugins, warnings

Is there a way to get all **Vulnerability / Security / Plugin - Warnings** that you can see in the Jenkins-Master-Webgui and print them in your terminal? 
I need a groovy-script that prints all warning data, but I don't know where the Information is stored. I can't find anything in $JENKINS_HOME.

I can get all my current Plugins and versions with:

```
    Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins.each{
      plugin ->
        println ("${plugin.getDisplayName()} (${plugin.getShortName()}): ${plugin.getVersion()}")
    }
```

But I can't even find a site published with all vulnerable plugin-versions for comparison.
[svn.dev.java.net/svn/hudson/trunk/hudson/plugins/warnings](http://svn.dev.java.net/svn/hudson/trunk/hudson/plugins/warnings) is not accessible. 
Also, I cannot use the warnings-plugin.

---

Some examples for Warnings:

- New version of Jenkins (2.89.4) is available for download (changelog). 
  Warnings have been published for the following currently installed components:
  Jenkins 2.89.3 core and libraries:
  Multiple security vulnerabilities in Jenkins 2.106 and earlier, and LTS 2.89.3 and earlier
- This Jenkins instance uses deprecated protocols: JNLP-connect,JNLP2-connect,JNLP3-connect. It may impact stability of the instance. If newer protocol versions are supported by all system components (agents, CLI and other clients), it is highly recommended to disable the deprecated protocols.